# I have a SQL record with 5 columns, I want to display it with 3 columns on row 1 and two columns on row 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN [AssignedUser] IS NULL 
          THEN 'Unassigned' 
          ELSE [AssignedUser] 
    END AS AssignedUser,
    [WorkItemId], [Created] AS 'Created Date',
    [AffectedUser], [TierDisplay].[DisplayString] AS 'Support Group',
    [UrgencyDisplay].[DisplayString] AS 'Incident Type', [Title],
    [Description] 
FROM
    [ServiceManagement].[dbo].[WorkItem] 
JOIN 
    [dbo].[DisplayString] AS StatusDisplay ON StatusDisplay.ElementID = WorkItem.StatusId -- Status
JOIN 
    [dbo].[DisplayString] AS TierDisplay ON TierDisplay.ElementID = WorkItem.TierId -- Support Group
JOIN 
    [dbo].[DisplayString] AS CatagoryDisplay ON CatagoryDisplay.ElementID = WorkItem.CategoryId -- Classification
JOIN 
    [dbo].[DisplayString] AS UrgencyDisplay ON UrgencyDisplay.ElementID = WorkItem.Urgency -- Ugency
WHERE 
    WorkItemId LIKE '%IR%'
    AND Created >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) --First day of previous DAY
    AND Created < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0) --First Day of current DAY
    AND [StatusDisplay].[displaystring] = 'Active' -- Only Active Status
    AND [TierDisplay].[DisplayString] = 'desktop support team' -- Only Desktop support Team
ORDER BY 
    AssignedUser  ASC
```

This is what it currently is displayed as

[image: Table1]

This is how I would like for it to be displayed:

[image: Table2]

Comment: yeah, you need to do this in the presentation layer, not in SQL Server

Comment: A query returns a data set.  What you are describing in the title is two different data sets, so you need two different queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not output table data like that using only t-sql. You must need to take help any reporting tool like crystal report to organize data to your need. If you really need it within sql server, then you can use temptable and add data to it according to your required structure.

Comment: The tool I have available will only accept a single SQL query.

Comment: It is impossible then by using only a single query.